# Unable to call ng-click on function inside the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a directive..i want to use a function defined inside the link function of the directive in the place where i have defined the template of my directive

app.js

```js
angular.module('app',[])
 .controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.name = "Vikram Prasad";
 })

 .directive('directive', function(){
  return{
   restrict:'A',
   templateUrl:'button.html',
   link:function(elems, attrs, scope){

    scope.index=0;
    scope.colors = ['red','blue','green','orange','brown'];
    scope.color = scope.colors[scope.index];

    scope.changeColor = function(){
     console.log('clicked');
     if(scope.index>scope.colors.length){
      scope.index = 0;
     }
     scope.color = scope.colors[scope.index];
     scope.index++;
    };
   }
  }
 });
```

directive template

```html
<div class="button" ng-class="color" ng-click="changeColor()">Click Me</div>
```

The ng-click on the template does not responds to the click.
What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: how you are using this directive.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had mistaken in `link` function parameter, `scope` comes first.

```
link:function(elems, attrs, scope){
```

should be

```
link:function(scope, elems, attrs){
```

Comment: thanks sir.. whats the concept behind this hierarchy sir ?

Comment: @VikramPrasad Please don't call sir, what do you mean by *concept behind this hierarchy*?

Comment: What was happening when i wrote scope as the last attribute?

Comment: @VikramPrasad this is how they are intended to use, its a function gets treated as `postLink` function at compilation time, take a look at [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) for more info